# Go SQL map 1:M relation json array to slice

Tags: postgresql, go, struct, sqlx

I have a `product-image (1:M)` relation and basically i want to map those images to a slice in my struct. I am using sqlx library to make it bit easier.

I searched for a while and maybe the best answer was in this thread: [Efficiently mapping one-to-many many-to-many database to struct in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54601529/efficiently-mapping-one-to-many-many-to-many-database-to-struct-in-golang).
The answer with creating the view and returning everything as a json works but it feels somehow hacky.

Ideally what i want to do is use postgres `json_agg` to return the json array inside the images column that would match my type so i could scan into it.

I did this with nodejs several times but here i don't know how. Do i need to implement custom `Scan` and `Value` methods or is there a simpler way. I didn't show this but i also have a category that is 1:1 and i can embed that category in product and do a left join and it works with sqlx, but not with images type.

**Simplified models**

```
type Image struct {
  ID int,
  URL string,
  ProductID int
}

type ImageList []*Image

type Product struct {
  ID int `db:"id"`
  Name string `db:"name"`
  Images ImageList `db:"images"`
}
```

**DB Tables**

```
create table product (
  id int generated always as identity primary key,
  name varchar(255),
);

create table product_image (
  id int generated always as identity primary key,
  url text not null,
  product_id int references product(id)
);
```

**I am trying something like this now:**

```
q := `SELECT 
      p.*,
      COALESCE(JSON_AGG(img.*) FILTER (WHERE img.product_id IS NOT NULL), '[]'::json) AS images
      FROM product p
      LEFT JOIN product_image img ON p.id = img.product_id
      WHERE p.id = 1
      GROUP BY p.id`

var p Product
if err := sqlxdb.Get(&p, q); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", err)
}
```

I get this error:

`sql: Scan error on column index 26, name "images": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *model.ImageList`

This seems like a super common scenario and yet i can't find any examples...
Or finally am i even stupid for doing this because i can just do forEach in JS and do like 50 queries to fetch all the images for every product.

Comment: Just curious, if a `product_image` row is joined with `ON p.id = img.product_id` would the filter where clause `WHERE img.product_id IS NOT NULL` ever result in `false`? Isn't it unnecessary?

Comment: You can implement the `sql.Scanner` interface for `*ImageList`, have the implementation type-assert the `interface{}` argument to `[]byte` and then pass the result of that, together with the receiver, to `json.Unmarshal`. i.e. https://play.golang.org/p/Zh50aAB3YA1

Comment: @mkopriva i tried but i actually get the same error, interesting. Thanks anyway for the help. And for the query if i don't write the filter, it actually gives me array with null inside like this. [null]. I guess there are other ways to this but this query works.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for getting list of items could be done using this mapping lib: [carta](https://github.com/jackskj/carta)

```
q := `SELECT p.*, img.id AS img_id, img.url AS img_url 
      FROM public.product p
      LEFT JOIN product_image img ON p.id = img.product_id`

    rows, err := sqlxdb.Query(q)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var products []*model.Product
    carta.Map(rows, &products)
```

And for the img struct i would use `db:"img_id`" prefix and so on, because i select with alias...